# Jquery Append On click function table

Tags: jquery, html

I am appending data to a table from an API call with jQuery.
What i want to do now though is if someone clicks on a row in the table i want to pass the id of the row to another screen (edit screen) to edit the details of the row.
When i try to add a click function to the row though it breaks as in the table doesn't populate with the data.
what i've tried

option 1

```
$.get(...){
$.each(res.data, function (index, value) {
 $(".TData").append('"<tr id="'+value.id'"><td>'+value.description+'</td> <td>'+value.order+' </td> </tr>"')
})
}


$(".TData tr").click(function(event){
console.log(event.id); <- doesn't return value.id
(in reality this will redirect to the next page passing the id)
})
```

and in line assignment of onclick

```
$.get(...){
$.each(res.data, function (index, value) {
 $(".TData").append('"<tr onclick="rowClick(e)" id="'+value.id'"><td>'+value.description+'</td> <td>'+value.order+' </td> </tr>"')
})
}


function rowClick...
```

neither of these approaches worked, in that the table didn't populate with option 2.
and under options 1 the id is never pushed into the console to do anything with. can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Fix your strings `'"` or rather use **Template Literals**
- Use JS `Array.prototype.map()` to create an Array of rows
- Use jQuery's Object notation **Element Options**
- **Append only once** after all your `$rows` array is populated (for better performance)
- Use **`.on()` method** to assign click listener to each row (see example below)

```js
const res = { // Just to fake the response
  "data": [
    {"id": 111, "description": "Lorem", "order": "Order 1"},
    {"id": 222, "description": "Ipsum", "order": "Order 2"}
  ]
};

const $rows = res.data.map(obj => $('<tr>', {
  id: obj.id,
  append: `<td>${obj.description}</td><td>${obj.order}</td>`,
  on: {
    click() {
      console.log(obj.id);
      // You can also use $(this) to reference the clicked row
    }
  }
}));

// Append only once:
$(".TData").append($rows);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Description</th><th>Order</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="TData"></tbody>
</table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

[MDN - Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
[MDN - Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[jQuery API - jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
[jQuery API - .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Tried that but only the <try> parts getting inserted. Seems that everything afterwards is ignored

Comment: @Martin I have no clue what is your specific issue. `<try>`..? You mean `<tr/>`?